# How to switch this syntax to ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var ACTION_TYPES = require('../actions').ACTION_TYPES;
```

I tried to import `{ACTION_TYPES.ACTION_TYPES} from ('../actions')` but it doesn't seem to work.

How to switch to ES6 using import?

Comment: How do you export ACTION_TYPES from actions?

Comment: I guess the form is a typo?  Should be from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
import {ACTION_TYPES} from '../actions'
```